# Firebase image not loading

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

```
String? downloadURL = userData['profile_image_url'];
if (downloadURL != null && downloadURL.isNotEmpty) {
  return CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(downloadURL), // <--- here
  );
} else {
  return CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/profile_picture_placeholder.png'),
  );
}
```

This is the error I get

> ======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
> The following ProgressEvent$ object was thrown resolving an image codec: [object ProgressEvent]

I have tried using a image link directly from google and that works but when loading a firebase storage image link it does not load the image

Comment: can you share the image url you uploaded on firebase?

Answer (score 0):

do you have [firebase storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) installed on your app? Otherwise your code is similar to what I use `CircleAvatar( backgroundImage: NetworkImage( user.imageUrl.isNotEmpty ? user.imageUrl : 'assets/images/blankp.png'), radius: 90, ),`

Comment: Yes i believe i have firebase storage installed, as i am able to upload the image to the ‘profile_images’ folder in my firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem very well because you didn't share the complete code .
But I always use the following steps to upload image to firebase storage.

1- Create class StorageMethods that contains upload to storage function.

```
    class StorageMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  // adding image to firebase storage
  Future<String> uploadImageToStorage(
    String childName,
    Uint8List file,
    bool ispost,
  ) async {
    // creating location to our firebase storage

    Reference ref =
        _storage.ref().child(childName).child(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
    // putting in uint8list format -> Upload task like a future but not future
    
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);

    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;

    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
}
```

2-call upload image function when ever you need to upload your image.

```
  String photoUrl = await StorageMethods()
          .uploadImageToStorage("ProfilePics", profilePic, false);
```

3- Now you have your photo url and you can use it in your circular avatar.

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photoUrl),
  )
```